# command-line tool for a single download of a torrent (like wget or curl)

Tags: command-line, wget, download, bittorrent, protocols

I'm interested in a single command that would download the contents of a torrent (and perhaps participate as a seed following the download, until I stop it).

Usually, there is a torrent-client daemon which should be started separately beforehand, and a client to control (like `transmission-remote`).

But I'm looking for the simplicity of `wget` or `curl`: give one command, get the result after a while.

Comment: Something like [aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/manual/en/html/README.html#bittorrent) e.g. `aria2c http://somesite/somefile.torrent` ?

Comment: You could use http://deluge-torrent.org/. That command line beast has an amazing CLI UI, GUI and even a web-UI for you to control.

Comment: `btdownloadcurses`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I gave a try to `lftp`:

```
lftp -c "torrent $1"
```

where `$1` is the `.torrent` file.

Unlike

```
lftp -e "torrent $1"
```

`lftp -c` must exit when the command is done (`lftp -e` leaves you in its command pronpt).

It also does seeding. (I don't know yet how seeding interacts with `-c`.)

### Seeding after the command finished

This is actually done by `lftp -c`:

first, I started it. And the command finished after a while:

```
Name: lib.ru_2007-03-05.7z
dn:1.7G up:0 complete, ratio:0.000000
Seeding in background...
[15137] Moving to background to complete transfers...
$
```

Checking that it is still active (seeding) in the background:

```
$ ps x | fgrep lftp
 15137 ?        Ss     0:37 lftp -c torrent lib.ru_2007-03-05.7z.4fb7e98d43804eca.torrent
 67517 pts/3    S+     0:00 grep -F --color=auto lftp
$
```

Answer (score 16):

Check out `transmission-cli`. The usage is as simple as running `transmission-cli <torrent-file>`, but you can obviously tune it to your needs with several options.

Just a side comment:

Actually you could use many other options, apart from `transmission-cli` and there will probably appear many other suggestions here (like `deluge` by Benjamin B. in the comments). I've read somewhere that any well-behaved program should be written so that it can be controlled via command line and the GUI is only an addition to that -- an interface to make the program easier or more convenient to use.

Comment: I agree with your side comment. It's just a matter of finding a decent BitTorrent client and launching it's CLI (it should have one). Personally I use Deluge, but I see now point adding it as an answer. @Erathiel, you can include it if you wish.

Comment: @BenjaminB. I've included your suggestion, though my guess is we'd end up with a very long list if we wanted to list every torrent client that can be controlled via command line :)

Comment: Interesting comment on how programs should be command line controllable. That matches fairly closely the classical unix philosophies of doing one thing simply and well per program, though seems to be becoming less popular these days for better or worse.

Comment: Does transmission-cli keep seeding indefinitely, by default? And is it possible to supply some seeding ratio - after which it exits?

Comment: @maxschlepzig As per [this man page for transmission-cli](https://linux.die.net/man/1/transmission-cli), you can use the `-f, --finish script` option to set a script that will be run when the download finishes.

Answer (score 13):

[**aria2**](https://aria2.github.io/)

```
aria2c <torrentfile or magnet link>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also try [rtorrent](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/) and may be [ctorrent](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ctorrent/) which man page starts with:

> ctorrent - Download bittorrent files from command line

Answer (score 3):

I just wrote `tget` - wget for torrents.

```
$ tget "magnet-link"

$ tget /path/to/ubuntu.torrent
```

To install, do `npm install -g t-get` or `yarn global add t-get`

More details - http://github.com/jeffjose/tget

Comment: Ended up using this because I didn't have root access. An overly straightforward & simplified tool but does the job fine.

Answer (score 3):

## You can use [torrent-dl](https://github.com/pigeonburger/torrent-dl)

It was originally based off of `tget`, a tool mentioned [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316831/436289), but the project has since significantly diverted from it. `tget` does not offer any configurability (e.g. searching popular torrent sites, customizing what port to use, downloading multiple torrents, etc) so `torrent-dl` adds all of these features.

Example usage (with some of the extra options):

```
torrent-dl -i magnet:?xt=urn:btih:b26c81363ac1a236765385a702aec107a49581b5 --port 43022 --connections 250 --uploadslots 25
```

You can see all the options it offers on it's Github page linked at the top. It is a nodejs application, however you can download standalone binaries (MacOS and Windows binaries are also available) from the releases page on it's Github, meaning no nodejs or npm installation is required.

It can also be installed via `npm`, however:

```
npm install -g torrent-dl
```

**I am the author of this project.**

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation without installing anything (if you have node)

```
npx -p webtorrent-cli webtorrent download "magent:..."
```

It's will temporary download the `webtorrent-cli` pakcage, then execute the `webtorretn` commmand to download your torrent.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old but I just stumbled on this today. I wrote something like this sometime back for kickasstorrents

[kscli](https://github.com/kodelint/kscli)

Try this and let me know if